# PHP increase max execution time for loop

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, php-ini

I have a `php` script this script contain a `for loop` inside this loop i have a `mysql` query to insert data into database.

When i test this script on my localhost this script work fine.

But when i try this script on my `shared server` on `godaddy` i have a problem.

This problem is the loop stop after certain time

I try a loop for 90 repetition only 36 insert are in my database not 90.

I have tried many thing

At the top of my code i put

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 
set_time_limit(0);
```

Also in my `.htaccess` i put this

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>
```

Also i check my `php.ini` (on godaddy server i don't have this file for that i have create this file and i put that on it)

```
max_execution_time = 300;
```

Also i have tried that

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000);
ini_set('memory_limit','960M');
```

And that

```
ob_start();

...and this code right before ending the loop:

echo ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

But all these solution doesn't work for me the same problem still it stop insert at 36 if i tried to insert 90 reputation 
Any body have a suggestion or solution for that ??!!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Why do you think the issue is to do with execution time?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't have an error because the code work on my localhost with the same example i put it

Comment: You're not telling much about what you're doing but maybe you should use a bulk insert syntax instead of a loop to insert 90 rows http://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/bulk-insert.php